# If statement isn't compiling on a json array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json array that looks like this:

```
Test = [
     {
      "adj" : [
                {
                  "nodeTo" : "x",
                  "nodeFrom" : "y",
                  "data": 
                      {
                        "$type" : "line",
                        "$color" : "#A989BC",
                        "$value" : "number"
                      }
                 }
               ],

      "id" : "id1",
      "name" : "name1"
     },
     {
      "adj" : [ ..... ]   // I have many element in the Test array
```

And I need to pass through all the elements in Test.
I have done this:

```
list = [];
for (i = 0; i < Test.lenght; i++) {
    if (x == Test[i]["name"])
           list.push(x + "->" + Test[i]["adj"][0]["nodeTo"] + ":" + Test[i]["adj"][0]["data"]["$value"]);
 }
```

But it is not working.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank you! It really was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably just a (very common) typo:   `i < Test.length;`

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?